# Optuna pdf uses dtrain = lgb.Dataset(train_x, label=train_y) - but what is the equivalent for xgb

Tags: xgboost, lightgbm, optuna

I really got a lot out of the Optuna documentation pdf https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/optuna/stable/optuna.pdf and followed it closely for the lightgbm training on the breast cancer data set.  I tried to follow the same procedure using xgboost on antoher data set but xgboost does not seem to have a similar command to the lightgbm.Dataset(X,y) command.  Does anyone know what the parallel command would be for xgboost?  Thanks.

Comment: You can use [`DMatrix`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.core) from xgboost.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried it specifically on the breast cancer data set and essentially the same as in the optima pdf.  Here is a piece of my code and the error message.  dtrain = xgb.Dataset(train_x, label=train_y)  
  dvalid = xgb.Dataset(valid_x, label=valid_y) - Sorry about the formatting in this message - can't figure out how to add a new line with a return key.  Error is ---AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute 'Dataset'

Comment: It is `DMatrix` not `Dataset`. [Refer here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.DMatrix). Your code should be `dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_x, label=train_y)`.

Comment: Thanks Kishore. That works! I need to read more carefully - i.e. not scan.  It has not solved my problem completely - but will try and figure it out myself,